# How to write a PicoLisp function that does not shadow variables with it's parameters

Tags: scope, lisp, dynamic-scope, picolisp

I am idly exploring PicoLisp, and find myself perplexed about how to write meta-programming functions that would traditionally be handled with macros (in other lisp dialects). The biggest source of concern for me is that I do not see how I can prevent variable name shadowing. Reviewing the examples in [Metaprogramming 101](http://picolisp.com/wiki/?metaprogramming101) has, if anything, just left me more confused.

Examples on how to implement the function `mapeach`, as seen in the linked article:

```
   [de mapeach "Args"    # expression
      (let [(@Var @List . @Body)  "Args"]
         (macro
            (mapcar
               '((@Var) . @Body)
               @List ]

   (de mapeach "Args"
      (mapcar
         (cons (cons (car "Args")) (cddr "Args"))
         (eval (cadr "Args")) ) )

   (de mapeach "Args"
      (mapcar
         '(("E")
            (bind (car "Args")
               (set (car "Args") "E")
               (run (cddr "Args")) ) )
         (eval (cadr "Args")) ) )

   (de mapeach "Args"
      (let "Vars" (pop '"Args")
         (apply mapcar
            (mapcar eval (cut (length "Vars") '"Args"))
            (cons "Vars" "Args") ) ) )
```

I have tested each of these with the call `(let "Args" * (mapeach N (1 2 3) ("Args" N N)))`. As expected, the PicoLisp interpreter (started with the command `pil +`) experiences a segfault and crashes. I assume this is because `mapeach`'s `"Args"` shadows the `"Args"` defined at call point.

I also tried both of their implementations of `map@` (the "cuter" alternative to `mapeach`).

```
   (de map@ "Args"
      (mapcar
         '(("E") (and "E" (run (cdr "Args"))))  # 'and' sets '@'
         (eval (car "Args")) ) )
   
   (de map@ "Args"
      (mapcar
         '((@) (run (cdr "Args")))
         (eval (car "Args")) ) )
```

I used `(let "Args" * (map@ (1 2 3) ("Args" @ @)))` to test each of those implementations. Bizarrely, the first time I tested the first implementation, not only did it *not* segfault, it actually produced the correct result `(1 4 9)`. Each subsequent test has resulted in a segfault. For clarity, the snippet from the prompt:

```
:  (de map@ "Args"
      (mapcar
         '(("E") (and "E" (run (cdr "Args"))))  # 'and' sets '@'
         (eval (car "Args")) ) )
-> map@
: (let "Args" * (mapeach N (1 2 3) ("Args" N N)))
!? (mapeach N (1 2 3) ("Args" N N))
mapeach -- Undefined
?                                                
: (let "Args" * (map@ (1 2 3) ("Args" @ @)))     
-> (1 4 9)
```

I believe that the segfault was somehow prevented by the call to the (then) undefined function `mapeach`, I also tried `(ooga booga)`, which similarly prevented the segfault. If I do not have the erroneous call separating the definition from the proper call, a segfault always occurs.

This ultimately culminates in 2 questions:

1. How can I prevent name shadowing? Clearly the examples do not succeed in that regard.
2. Why does that call to map@ *not* result in a segfault?

Comment: Maybe using anonymous (transient) symbols? (https://software-lab.de/doc/ref.html#symbol)

Comment: That's a part of my confusion, `"Args"` *is* a transient symbol. I tried generating a function that used an anonymous transient symbol for it's argument list, and it didn't really work. However, I think a better understanding of transient symbols may be key to solving my problem. I believe the answer is that "The index for transient symbols is cleared automatically before and after loading a source file, or it can be reset explicitly with the ==== function".  It does not seem to automatically reset during ordinary REPL use. https://software-lab.de/doc/ref.html#transient-io

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[According to this](https://software-lab.de/doc/ref.html#transient-io) "The index for transient symbols is cleared automatically before and after loading a source file, or it can be reset explicitly with the ==== function". It doesn't specify any way that it is automatically cleared during regular REPL usage, which is the context in which I was testing this.

This code runs properly:

```
[de mapeach "Args"    # expression
      (let [(@Var @List . @Body)  "Args"]
         (macro
            (mapcar
               '((@Var) . @Body)
               @List ]
(====)
(let "Args" * (mapeach N (1 2 3) ("Args" N N)))
```

It also runs as expected without the call to `====`, but only if the call to `mapeach` is not in the same file.

To address the 2 parts of my question:

1. You can prevent name shadowing by using transient symbols either in different files, or followed by a call to `====`.
2. Those calls likely worked because the debugger clears the index which contains the transient symbols.